# Почему на нашем SO нет значков у меток?

Tags: обсуждение, метки

На enSO у меток есть значки. Например, у kotlin, у android, у firebase, у sql-server, и т.п. Почему на нашем Стеке такого нет?

[image: Android]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это своего рода реклама. Наличие иконки спонсируется компанией к которой относится соответствующая метка (тут подробнее: [What do icons on the tags mean?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30187/what-do-icons-on-the-tags-mean))

Comment: Почему же на ruSO такого нет?

Comment: @AntonSorokin потому что Google и MS до лампочки RU SO? Яндекс, может быть, заинтересовался бы, так как некоторые сотрудники тут отвечают.